# Hints for building clisp-2.49

Tags: clisp

Any attempt to build clisp-2.49 fails because configure cannot find libsigsegv. I had already built libsigsegv and I can see it in /usr/lib. I have tried `configure` (with no options) and also using `--with-libsigsegv-prefix=/usr/lib` and `--with-libsigsegv-prefix=/usr`.

`configure` is giving me some helpful hints at retrieving and building the library locally - but that's not the point: the installed library should be found and used. *Can anyone offer any advice?*

(I also note that the instructions provided by configure allude to installing an older version of libsigsegv (2.8) I already have the current 2.10).

Many thanks, R.

Comment: please take a look at the logs (config.log) and figure out why libsigsegv is not detected. you might also want to try mercurial tip instead of the released version.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. `config.log` didn't help but it's nice to know about that for future. I deleted the entire directory and re-extracted it from the archive - and it works! I can only assume a stupid error at some point.